# Correct ESC amperage for a small electric motor

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor, remote-control, motor-controller

I disassembled a drone. I want to re-use two of its motors to build a twin-engine RC model plane.

My motors are best for 3.7v, and according to their reference, draw 0.18A-0.20A of current.

**What ESCs would I need, current-wise?**

It seems like all ESCs on the market are from 6A and up; What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Shopping recommendations are off-topic, so your question is in risk of being closed unless you edit and reword it.

Comment: I hope it's better now.

Comment: I think you have those specs wrong. Not even a mini drone (smaller than a hand) uses such little power.

Comment: Could be. I tried looking up their specs, this is what i found: http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-DC-3V-3-7V-27500-31000rpm-High-speed-N50-HM-Motor-Micro-DC-Magnetic-Motor-/182147624762?rmvSB=true

Comment: I suspect those are the "no load" current ratings, with just the shaft spinning and whatever internal friction is in the motor.  If you connect it to a propeller in air the RPM will drop slightly and the current draw will go way up.  That is, assuming the rating isn't just completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.18A and 0.2A are the no-load figures. Expect 2~5 times higher operating current depending on prop size, and ~10 times higher stall current.

> It seems like all ESCs on the market are from 6A and up; What am I
>   missing?

Here's one rated for 3A:-

[HobbyKing 3A Single Cell ESC - Brushed Micro Motors](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/hobbyking-3a-single-cell-esc-brushed-micro-motors.html/?___store=en_us)

A 2A ESC would probably be fine, but there's little point producing such a small controller when a higher rating can be achieved at minimal extra cost. A 6A controller should be more robust and efficient, if perhaps a little heavier.

Comment: And the motor will only draw "as much as it needs"? There's no danger in putting in even a 10A ESC?